# Is there a journal or 'place' to publish poems written by and for other researcher in the same field?

Tags: publications

I've seen poems squeezed in-between chapters in books, but I don't want to write a book for each poem :-) . Hence my question:

Is there a journal or 'place' to publish poems written by and for other researcher in the same field?

What I have in mind is for example a poem written for physicists.

Comment: On your personal website or in a normal poetry anthology are two possibilities I can think of.

Comment: Write your own book and put them in there?

Comment: There might be a blog.

Comment: Web of Science indexed 4,117 "poetry" items in 2017 - they do all indeed seem to be poetry rather than critical works. On the other hand, they're almost all in literary journals, but there was one in the _Australasian Journal of Information Systems_ and another was in the _Journal of Palliative Medicine_...

Answer (score 5):

In mathematics, the Mathematical Association of America has several journals aimed at undergraduate students (which many researchers also read): the *American Mathematical Monthly*, *College Mathematics Journal*, and *Mathematics Magazine*.  All of them regularly publish short poems related to math. (Often they appear in the otherwise empty space on the last page of a regular article).

Answer (score 2):

Some scientific journals publish letters to the editor that may include jokes, anecdotes, and even poetry.  *The New England Journal of Medicine* has traditionally been notable for the humor and literary quality of its letters column.

In physics, the *American Journal of Physics* used to publish short humorous letters of this type.  (I recall one letter from David Mermin setting out the absurd theory that Newton's use of "p" for momentum was an abbreviation for "pimento.")  However, it seems that they may not publish such items any longer.

Answer (score 1):

The *Journal of Humanistic Mathematics* has sections called *Poetry Folder* and *Poetry*.

From [their website](http://scholarship.claremont.edu/jhm/about.html) (emphasis mine):

> We publish articles that focus mainly on the doing of mathematics, the teaching of mathematics, and the living of mathematics. We also welcome contributions about the state of the mathematical profession (both in research and in education), underrepresentation issues within the world of mathematics, mathematics across national and cultural boundaries, *mathematical fiction and poetry*, personal reflections that provide insight to the inner workings of the mathematical mind, and other types of writing which may stimulate discussion among our readers. Overall we are a free platform where many different conversations about mathematics are welcome and encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Poetry is for everyone!

If you're in a university, get in touch with your arts and humanities faculty for advice or even potential collaboration. I am sure there would be interest.

Of course, you could also publish your own book in print or share online via a blog.

But if you're interested in reaching a particular audience in your field, you can always informally contact the editors of a journal you know to see if they would want to share your poetry in spare pages of an issue. I've not seem in it in the hard sciences, but occasionally see this sort of thing in arts, humanities and social sciences journals.

On the topic of poetry and physics, many winters ago I was taught by Mario Petrucci, the author of a poetry anthology that used imagery from nuclear physics as a motif to articulate the tragedy of Chernobyl:

[Petrucci, M. (2004) Heavy Water](https://enitharmon.co.uk/product/heavy-water-poem-chernobyl/)